# Output video file of ffmpeg command video and audio doesn't match

Tags: php, audio, video, ffmpeg

i'm trying to trim a video file using ffmpeg using this command
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:05:20 -t 00:10:00 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4` . The problem is when i open the output video, the audio starts normally but the video appears only 5 seconds after. I tried removing the `-c copy` option and output is accurate but the process is very slow. So my question is how to make output video/audio match when using `-c copy` option, or how to make the process faster when not using `-c copy` option. It's my first time using this so i don't know much about video/audio encoding, i am just trying to extract a video clip from a php script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when audio is ahead of video the `-async` switch auto-corrects the start of the audio stream when passed as `-async 1`. So try running

```
ffmpeg -async 1 -i input.mp4 -ss 00:05:20 -t 00:10:00 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: still doesn't work, when i play the output video, it's black screen with audio, and video show after 5 seconds